# Synchronize window mobile application with central database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, windows-mobile

My requirement is to create a windows mobile  6.1 app [for a window PDA] that works most time in offline, and when it  has connection it should work online to synchronize the data from PDA to server and server to PDA to keep the local and central database up to date.

There will be lots of transactions inside PDA and online too.The app will run more than one PDAs. So there will be lots of transactions in every PDA and it should sync with the central server when it is online.

How can I achieve this? Can I use microsoft synch service to do it? or any  better other methods to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you can use [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608) to do it.

However, quoting word to word from microsoft,

The major disadvantages to this solution are:

- Changes are required in the central database schema to add columns
  and tables that may affect current applications.
- Triggers are fired
  for each change made to a row, which has performance implications.
- Logic for maintaining proper rowversions and row deletions can get
  extremely complicated.
- Long running transactions can result in some
  data being missed during synchronization, resulting in data
  inconsistencies.

You are in very much luck if the master database is in SQL Server 2008 though. Read "Challenges of Building an OCA" section in the [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608) because there's no point in pasting everything here :)

Comment: Thank you for your help,              And i want to know one more thing,that can i filter data to be retrieve from central DB to LOcal PDA based on pda's certain criteria.[Means i dont want to load all central data to pda,instead i want to load only some data that is depend on pda's information in central database itself.]

Comment: I don't know whether it will work for but what you are looking for is Views.

Comment: yes exactly like views..but can i synch views to PDA??? for that wat could i maintain in PDA and central DB...thanks for ur kind help.

Comment: and do u think any other alternative to the above to maintain . keep data in xml/json format locally and pass it to web service that will procee the data and change to central db and so and so........   :)

Comment: I honestly don't know whether you can sync views to PDA. And to answer your other question, if you think you can build a more solid implementation of data synchronization between a server and a client than MSF, you should totally do it! BUT **please** read the article I posted and all the trouble the MS engineers had to go through to create the sync framework.